# UserPrincipal.Current.EmailAddress returning NULL value in .NET Framework 4.8

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I wrote a program that gets the email address of the user using my winform program. This program was written a few years ago under .NET framework 4.0. To get the user's email address I use this line of code:

```
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
string sUserEmailAddress =  UserPrincipal.Current.EmailAddress;
```

This worked. A couple of days ago my computer crashed. I got a new computer and had to reinstall VS22 and .NET Framework is 4.8. Now when I run the program I don't get the users email address. I stepped through the program and sUserEmailAddress = NULL. When I used the Immediate Window this is what I get:

```
UserPrincipal.Current.EmailAddress
error CS0103: The name 'UserPrincipal' does not exist in the current context
```

What am I missing? Is there a setting that I am missing?

Here is the top half of my code:

```
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;   

namespace InvoiceEmailer
   {
    public partial class frmInvEmailer : Form
    {
    
    System.Data.DataTable dtConvertBills = new System.Data.DataTable();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    Document document = null;
    ArrayList cl = new ArrayList();
    Hashtable cm = new Hashtable();
    public static StreamWriter swl;


    String sTranUno = "";
    String emailAddress1 = "";
    private string sUserId = "";
    private string sUserEmailAddress = UserPrincipal.Current.EmailAddress;
```

Comment: When you step through, and look at UserPrincipal what are the values you can see?

Comment: When I run the program and stop it at the above code and hover my mouse over 'UserPrinicipal' nothing happens. I then copied it to the Immediate Window and I get the same as above.

Comment: The intellisense works. When I type in UserPrinicipal I do see Current when I add a period, and then EmailAddress when I add a period after Current. Because of this I am assuming I have declared it correctly.

Comment: Can you expand your code more to show how you are getting the `UserPrincipal` please

Comment: Hello, is your issue solved? I re-edited the answer, it should make the version number of System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement consistent.

Answer (score -1):

I also introduced System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement and used UserPrincipal.Current.EmailAddress. There is no error CS0103. However, there are mainly the following solutions for this kind of error.

**Solution 1**: Reinstall your System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement nuget package.

**Solution 2**: The full name of UserPrincipal is System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal, so please change it to

```
string sUserEmailAddress = System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.Current.EmailAddress;
```

**Solution 3**: The version numbers of System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement under the web.config of the view and the Web.config of the project are inconsistent. You need to compare the System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement version of the View to make their System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement version numbers consistent.